Positional Encodings when testing on sequences with different lengths than the input dataset
I'm developing a neural network for a physical simulation which basically boils down to taking in a sequence of 3x3 matrices (representing some physical quantities) and outputting another sequence. Currently, I am using a sinusoidal positional encoding followed by a sequence of alternating attention/MLP layers.
However, I also need my model to be able to run inference on sequences of different lengths (up to 324 matrices), but my dataset only contains input/output sequences of length 9.
For this reason, I was wondering whether a sinusoidal positional encoding would be able to generalize well to sequences of different lengths or if there is a better option available. I have heard about various other schemes (RoPE, learned embeddings etc.) but I am still new to machine learning so I am not sure which would be the best for my specific use case, and would really appreciate some advice on the matter.
Thank you!
